# How to configure Brackets and GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab, brackets

I am trying to configure Brackets with GitLab using the following resources:
[Brackets Extension for GitLab](https://github.com/samura/brackets-gitlab)
Now for that we need [Brackets Integration with Git](https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-git).

1. **Git Integration**
   I have followed the integration steps provided for **Git** Integration but I don't understand the steps completely. Need help to simplify the instructions and test the integration
2. **GitLab Integration**
   [Brackets GitLab config window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB9mH.jpg)

I have followed the steps for these and added the extension. The extension asks for 2 values in its config window:
 **GitLab Api Url** is this the correct value - *https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects*

**Private Key** - Should this be the local path where the PPK file is?

Kindly suggest.

Thanks